# Escape slash in angular.js scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some controller with requests for filter, In database my table is sale/rent (it is not my idea, it is too late change name ow table). I am trying to show some objects by this line:

```
$scope.sale/rent = 'Sale';
```

Without escape slash i got an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment.

Ok, just escape this slash like this right?

```
$scope.sale/\/rent = 'Sale';
```

But no luck, still got error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

I don't understand how to escape slash here and make an request. Help please, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried Try $scope['sale/rent']?

Comment: You can NEVER name a variable like that with a slash. it will never compile. If there is a slash in your variable as a value than it is still considerable.

Comment: uhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is less an Angular-specific issue and more of a Javascript one-- if you're dealing with non-alphanumeric characters in a property name, you can use square bracket notation:

```
$scope["sale/rent"] = 'Sale';
```

I *should* specify, though-- I'm not really sure how/if the template will consume it properly...

edit: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865892/angular-binding-to-square-bracket-notation-property-with-a-space#26865992) is a StackOverflow discussing how to access square bracket properties in templates.